# How to transform between sources when they are in parallel?

Tags: current-source, thevenin, voltage-source, source, norton

Imagine you are given this circuit, and you want to transform the current generator into a voltage one, and then, find out the Thevenin and Norton Equivalents.

[image]

At first glance, what you might think to do is to put the resistance R2 in series with the current generator (now converted into a voltage one).

[image]

Is this correct? If not, how would you convert it properly?

Comment: if current source "ɑ i1" is an ideal current source, then the series resistor R1 has no effect.

Comment: thevenin-equivalent and norton-equivalent circuits are two different results (as I was taught, anyway.). I have never heard of one circuit called a "thevenin-norton-equivalent."  Is it possible you were asked to produce two (2) answers?

Comment: @RichS Yes, maybe I made it a little bit confusing, but I mean that. To do the Thevenin and then Norton Equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a first hint: R<sub>1</sub> is surplus to requirements just like a resistor in parallel with a voltage source will not have any influence on the transformation of a voltage source into a current source (extra hint). Hence, your circuit shown is incorrect. I'm hinting because this is clearly a homework question and we don't supply direct answers to homework; we make you work at it via hints etc..

Comment: I don't quite exactly know how to take that into account onto the circuit...

Comment: Do you know how to convert a voltage source and series resistor into a current source @ÁlvaroRodrigo?

Comment: Yes. But is that useful to do in this context?

Comment: If you transfer the voltage source to a current source, you then have two current sources in parallel and, that means they can be very simply combined into one current source. Doesn't that sound useful to you @ÁlvaroRodrigo?

Comment: Oh my god, thanks, i feel dumb now. It was that easy...